# Mutt mail - read / unseen flag not syncing with server

Tags: terminal, email, mutt

Mutt is connected to a Gmail address via IMAP.

When a new message arrives, quite rightly it is marked with 'N' within the index.
Reading the email, this flag is removed ... however any other clients / gmail.com still displays the email as being unread.

I have gone through the Mutt doc but cannot find anything about updating the unseen flag on the server.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a limitation to Mutt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mutt and neomutt you need to sync mailbox to write changes to the backend. It doesn't matter if the backend is maildir, imap or notmuch.

The function is called `<sync-mailbox>` and is bound to `$` by default. Changing the mailbox to a different one or closing mutt should trigger the sync-mailbox function too.

Comment: Fantastic, I see now. Thank you for clearing that up.